# How to access elements using Javascript with no id?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access an element that has no id and has a shared classname, using Javascript. How can I successfully do that?

I tried using `document.getElementsbyClassName` property, but since the classname is shared by other elements, this is not working.

```
   <a class="sharedClass anotherClass" href="www.mybooks.com" data-m="{"CN":"uniquename"}"> Proceed </a>
```

I want to be able to click the `Proceed` element from the above code. Please note that `uniquename` is unique to this element. I'm thinking we can use that somehow here but am not really sure.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('className') will return an array of elements that have that class. you can iterate through that array to access the element.

Comment: Can you provide valid HTML? Your double quotes are breaking syntax

Comment: You need to share snippet, so we can follow you more efficiently. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Buffalo alluded to in his comment, you could get a list of all elements sharing the class name and loop over the result set and check the `data-m` attribute until you find the one you want:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("sharedClass");
var myElement;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i].getAttribute("data-m") == '{"CN":"uniquename"}') {
    myElement = elements[i];
  }
}

console.log(myElement);
```

```html
<a class="sharedClass anotherClass" href="www.mybooks.com" data-m='{"CN":"uniquename"}'> Proceed </a>
<a class="sharedClass anotherClass" href="www.mybooks.com" data-m='{"CN":"uniquename2"}'> Proceed </a>
```

You can also be a bit more succinct by leveraging `querySelector` instead:

```js
var myElement = document.querySelector("[data-m='{\"CN\":\"uniquename\"}");
console.log(myElement);
```

```html
<a class="sharedClass anotherClass" href="www.mybooks.com" data-m='{"CN":"uniquename"}'> Proceed </a>
<a class="sharedClass anotherClass" href="www.mybooks.com" data-m='{"CN":"uniquename2"}'> Proceed </a>
```